# Mini 360 DC Buck Converter

Tags: 12v, step-down, 24v

I have bought several DC Buck converters for my home-made 3D printer. I'm running a 24V PSU, but my fans are Noctua (12V) ones. So i want to convert 24V down to 12V. And the Voltage output works fine. however after several minutes the module gets really hot to the touch. Up to the point that it is not touchable with your base hands. Is this 'normal'?

The unit I'm talking about is this one: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Hot-sale-Mini-360-DC-DC-Buck-Converter-Step-Down-Module-Mini360-4-75V-23V-to/32825363837.html

Comment: How much current are you drawing?

Comment: You should probably ask the person who's sold you the component, not strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is because as shown [here](https://solarbotics.com/product/40410/) as well as on your aliexpress link, the voltage that you are feeding is over the maximum accepted input voltage, which is 23V.

That additional volt you add, might not be enough to destroy the module, but it is high enough to make it overheat.

Comment: I see! Didn't think it mattered that much! apparently it does. Thanks for clarifying